# Showing monotonicity and limit of a first-order non-homogeneous recurrence relation with variable coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, limits, recurrence-relations

The form I am thinking of is $a_n = c - na_{n-1}$, where $c$ is a constant.

If $a_1$ and $c$ are provided, I'd like to show whether the sequence of $a_n$ is monotone and/or has a limit.

In this case the explicit form is an unhelpful combination of the gamma and subfactorial functions. Induction does not seem to make any headway.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: You must know *something* about $f(n)$ to draw any conclusions about $a_n$.

Comment: Thank you, that is quite obvious in retrospect. I'll edit my question.

Comment: If it had a limit then $L = c - L \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} n$, which is not possible unless $c=a_1=0$. Also, $\frac{a_n}{n!} = -\frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + c\,\frac{1}{n!} = \frac{a_{n-2}}{(n-2)!} + c\left(\frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\right)=\dots\;$ shows that the even and odd subsequences of $\frac{a_n}{n!}$ both converge.